# Wrapper Class SOQL not retrieving dynamic values

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql, wrapper-class

I have created a Wrapper class to present data from different objects `Event__c` and `Campaign`. The class works fine when I hardcode the values for the SOQL statements but when I assign the dynamic values retrieved form a visual force page the table is empty. `selectedCampaignValue` and `selectedEventValue`  are values retrieved from pick lists.

**Wrapper Controller**

```
 public with sharing class WrapperClassExtension {


    public String selectedCampaignValue {get; set;}
    public String selectedEventValue {get; set; }
    public List<WrapList> countList {get; set;}

    public WrapperClassExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {


    }

    public List<WrapList> getCounts(){

          countList = new List<WrapList>();

    for(Campaign c : [SELECT id,Name,isActive,NumberOfContacts FROM Campaign WHERE Name LIKE :selectedCampaignValue AND IsActive = True LIMIT 1]){
        for(Event__c ev : [SELECT id,Event_Id__c,Event_Name__c,Event_Attendees_Count__c  FROM Event__c WHERE Event_Name__c LIKE :selectedEventValue LIMIT 1]){
     /*Create a new wrapper and add it to list*/
     countList.add(new WrapList(c,ev));
   }
   }
   return countList;
 }

    public class WrapList {

    public Campaign cCount { get; set; }
    public Event__c evCount { get; set; }


    public WrapList(Campaign c, Event__c ev) {
        this.cCount = c;
        this.evCount = ev;
    }


    }


}
```

**Visualforce**

```
<apex:pageBlock id="results_count" title="Count" rendered="{!attending != null}">
      <apex:pageMessages />
      <apex:pageBlockSection title="DelegateManager Total - {!selectedEventValue}" columns="1" collapsible="true">
        <apex:outputText style="font-style:italic"
          value="Delegates attending the specified event are listed below. Click the 'Sync All' button to synchronize your Salesforce records with DelegateManager delegates. If you wish to receive an email with a csv file containing failed syncs for the event then press 'Email Csv'."></apex:outputText>
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Counts}" var="c" rows="1">
          <apex:column headerValue="DelegateManager Total" style="width:30px;">
            <apex:outputText value="{!c.evCount.Event_Attendees_Count__c}"/>
          </apex:column>
          <apex:column headerValue="Campaign Members Total" style="width:75px;">
            <apex:outputText value="{!c.cCount.NumberOfContacts}"/>
          </apex:column>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
      </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
```

Comment: Are you sure you are receiving good values for these two parameters?

Comment: just noticed those values return null on the debug log however i am using those in other classes and work fine. thats strange @JeremyNottingham

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do a "contains" search, then you need to wrap the input in wildcard characters (`%`). For example:

```
String campaignSearchTerm = '%' + selectedCampaignValue + '%';
String eventSearchTerm = '%' + selectedEventValue + '%';
for ([SELECT ... FROM Campaign WHERE Name LIKE :campaignSearchTerm LIMIT 1]) { ... }
```

Comment: Tried that as well but not getting results still